# Find the cdf of the third smallest among $ X_{1},... , X_{8} $

Tags: probability-distributions

We have $ X_{1},... , X_{8} $. All independent exponential r.v. with mean $ 1 $. I know how to find the cdf of the smallest among them, but i didn't see how to find the third smallest and its expected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_{(3)}$ be the third-smallest of $X_1, \ldots, X_8$.  Then $X_{(3)} < x$ if and only if at least three of $X_1, \ldots, X_8$ are less than $x$.  Now, $P(X_1 < x) = 1 - e^{-x}$ (and similarly for $X_2, \ldots, X_8$).  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I got it, thank you